# How to trim a page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I have a React application running where I am getting a page from an external ASP.NET app. I will like get just a section of the page and not the complete page. I do not know if it is possible to do that. My goal is to strip just the body of the page. My page goes as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Privacy Policy - DotnetApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">DotnetApp</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <h1>Privacy Policy</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>

        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - DotnetApp - <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I will like to get everything inside the `<body> </body>` tag. Below is my app

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export function setup(app) {

    const connect = app.createConnector(() => fetch('https://localhost:44393/Home/Privacy').then(res => res.text()));
    app.registerPage('/mypage', connect(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data)
        const ref = React.useRef();

        var tmp = document.createElement("div");
        return (<div className="Container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
            data}}></div>)

    }));
}
```

the data object holds the HTML page above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DOMParser interface to parse html as a DOM tree. For example:

```
let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><!-- some html --></html>'
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
let bodyHtml = doc.body.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This works pretty well when html is defined ash shown in your answer. but in my case I have a data object and putting it jlike let html = data  rendered the complete page instead of the body

Comment: By the complete page, are you referring to the contents of the body element, including the header and footer?

Comment: I see where the Problem lies. Is there no possibility to get the <div class="container">
element? Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, you can retrieve it with this: `doc.querySelector('.container').outerHTML;`